# if statement not showing results?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If a field in my database is equal to a number, a certain number of images should be displayed in my view.

> **E.g.** if field 'star rating' is equal to 3, than 3 images should be visible
>   (two hidden, 3 visible)

The below code works when star rating is equal to 0, but for some reason, if 'star rating' field is equal to any other number (e.g. 3), all 5 images are still displayed? Am I missing something?

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *neighbours = neighbourDetail;
    NSLog(@"This is neighbours detail info %@", neighbours);

    if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"0"]) {
        self.pawOne.hidden = YES;
        self.pawTwo.hidden = YES;
        self.pawThree.hidden = YES;
        self.pawFour.hidden = YES;
        self.pawFive.hidden = YES;

        if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"1"]) {
            self.pawOne.hidden = NO;
            self.pawTwo.hidden = YES;
            self.pawThree.hidden = YES;
            self.pawFour.hidden = YES;
            self.pawFive.hidden = YES;

            if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"2"]) {
                self.pawOne.hidden = NO;
                self.pawTwo.hidden = NO;
                self.pawThree.hidden = YES;
                self.pawFour.hidden = YES;
                self.pawFive.hidden = YES;

                if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"3"]) {
                    self.pawOne.hidden = NO;
                    self.pawTwo.hidden = NO;
                    self.pawThree.hidden = NO;
                    self.pawFour.hidden = YES;
                    self.pawFive.hidden = YES;

                    if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"4"]) {
                        self.pawOne.hidden = NO;
                        self.pawTwo.hidden = NO;
                        self.pawThree.hidden = NO;
                        self.pawFour.hidden = NO;
                        self.pawFive.hidden = YES;

                        if ([[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"star rating"] isEqual:@"5"]) {
                            self.pawOne.hidden = NO;
                            self.pawTwo.hidden = NO;
                            self.pawThree.hidden = NO;
                            self.pawFour.hidden = NO;
                            self.pawFive.hidden = NO;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code so you can easily see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is the improper nesting of the `if` statements. If the value isn't `@"0"` it will never check any other value.

The proper format would be:

```
if (some condition 1) {
} else if (some condition 2) {
} else if (some condition 3) {
} else {
}
```

But there is a much simpler way to write your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *neighbours = neighbourDetail;
    int rating = [neighbourDetail[@"star rating"] intValue];
    self.pawOne.hidden = rating == 0;
    self.pawTwo.hidden = rating <= 1;
    self.pawThree.hidden = rating <= 2;
    self.pawFour.hidden = rating <= 3;
    self.pawFive.hidden = rating <= 4;
}
```

And this would be even easier if your `pawXXX` views were in an array instead of having 5 separate properties.

Comment: Good call. I should have looked at the code more closely.

Answer (score 1):

You have each if statement inside the previous one.

The body of the first if statement is ony executed if star rating is "1". Then, inside that if statement, the next if statement will only be executed if star rating is "2". But you already determined that it's "1".

If you're going to use a series of if statements like that then you need to close each if statement and then have a separate if statement after that. However, a switch statement is a better construct for this situation. Convert the star rating to an nit and use a switch statement.